# BootStrap Parsley minimum amount with decimal place validation fails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, parsley.js

parsley will not validate minimum amount for a input type='number' properly when there is decimal places in the amount. Removing the decimal places works, but that's not an option..

validation works with a input type='text', but is it possible to work around the html5 limitation in type='number' ?

I created a codepen (fiddle seems to have trouble with parsley )
http://codepen.io/bwolfsohn/pen/eJzbpQ

minimum Bid with .00 in validation

```
<form class="form-inline bidding" name="IamBidding" ACTION="#" METHOD="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="mb mbinlinebox" TYPE="number"  min="925.00" id="aBidAmount_7167" VALUE="925.00" name="aBidAmount_7167" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-error-message="You must enter at least 925.00" size="11" maxlength="11" required />
<input type="hidden" name="toa" value="IamBidding" />
<input type="hidden" name="bidtype" value="U" />
<input TYPE="hidden" name="aMin_7167" VALUE="925.00" />
<input TYPE='submit' VALUE="Bid Now" Name="Submit" class='btn btn-success' />
</div></form>
```

minimum Bid  with 25 cents

```
<form class="form-inline bidding" name="IamBidding" ACTION="#" METHOD="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="mb mbinlinebox" TYPE="number"  min="925.25" id="aBidAmount_7167" VALUE="925.25" name="aBidAmount_7167" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-error-message="You must enter at least 925.25" size="11" maxlength="11" required />
<input type="hidden" name="toa" value="IamBidding" />
<input type="hidden" name="bidtype" value="U" />
<input TYPE="hidden" name="aMin_7167" VALUE="925.25" />
<input TYPE='submit' VALUE="Bid Now" Name="Submit" class='btn btn-success' />
</div></form>
```

minimum Bid validation without decimal places

```
<form class="form-inline bidding" name="IamBidding" ACTION="#" METHOD="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="mb mbinlinebox" TYPE="number"  min="925" id="aBidAmount_7167" VALUE="925" name="aBidAmount_7167" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-error-message="You must enter at least 925" size="11" maxlength="11" required />
<input type="hidden" name="toa" value="IamBidding" />
<input type="hidden" name="bidtype" value="U" />
<input TYPE="hidden" name="aMin_7167" VALUE="925" />
<input TYPE='submit' VALUE="Bid Now" Name="Submit" class='btn btn-success' />
</div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should specify `step="0.01"`. Otherwise the default step is 1 and that's not what you want!

Comment: Note that [bugs](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/1037) in parsley made that less than clear...